# Scale or resize an 8bit image with 8bit image as result (PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)

Tags: c#, .net, image, resize, 8-bit

I try to scale a grey8 image for video transmission via TCP-clients in C#/.NET.
My image from an IpCam is currently 1920x1080 and I want to resize it to 640x480 in order to reduce traffic on the connection:

I found a working example here on Stack Overflow the only problem is.

```
 public static Image ResizeImage(Bitmap image, Size size, bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
    {
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;
        if (preserveAspectRatio)
        {
            int originalWidth = image.Width;
            int originalHeight = image.Height;
            float percentWidth = (float)size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
            float percentHeight = (float)size.Height / (float)originalHeight;
            float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);
        }
        else
        {
            newWidth = size.Width;
            newHeight = size.Height;
        }
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; //NearestNeighbor
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        
        return(newImage);
    }
```

.the image I get from this function is a 32ARgb image, which is not what I want. Because it introduces 3 additional color channels (Alpha and RBG).
Is there a way of scaling the image down without changing the color pattern?

I also tried to use the InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor but I only got a 32bit-bitmap out of it.

Comment: you mean the Bitmap (int height, int size, Pixelformat pixelformat)? and how to copy in it the old picture? Do i have to use Bitmap.clone()?

Comment: I also thought about bringing the constructor direcly into the game  on <newImage> definition but then i will get an error: grafic object can't be create from  a pitcure with indexed Pixelformat

Comment: I also tried the following line:var newBmp = ConvertedImage.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, ConvertedImage.Width,ConvertedImage.Height), PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

Comment: Do i have to copy the ColorPalette from the original image and redraw it on the new image?

Comment: Final what i want is  1024x768(Format8bppIndexed) ->500x375(Format8bppIndexed). Right now the code does the resize but it outputs an 32Argb (with 4 channels à 8bit). But i want to keep the ColorPalette form the 8bppIndexed one. How can i achieve this? i have to downsize the 4*8bit to 8bit I think, or is there a better way? Or can i save the ColorPalette from the big 8bpp Image and assign it to the 32Argb bitmap?

Comment: what about such a solution?[link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319061)